# Selecting an element from within an array using javascript and time delays

Tags: javascript

I am posting an answer to a question I could not find.

```
var imgs=[];
doge=new imgage_wrapper("50","10","10","doge1.png");
imgs.push(doge);


for(var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++)
{
    var test = imgs[i];
    setTimeout(function(){test.destructor()},1000);
}
```

This works. 
However,

```
for(var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++)
{
    setTimeout(function(){imgs[i].destructor()},1000);
}
```

Does not work.
That is the answer.

Now, I am not sure I know WHY this is the answer. Can you illuminate me?

Comment: Actually none of them works, they both have the classic closure inside loops issue

Comment: @adeneo The first one happens to work in this case because `imgs.length` is 1 and `test` ends up being the last value in `imgs`.

Comment: @melpomene - it doesn't work when it doesn't do what it's supposed to. The difference is the first one doesn't throw an error, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @adeneo What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: The `test` variable is overwritten in each iteration, surely that isn't what the OP intended when he iterated over an array

Answer (score 0):

Both examples have nested functions that use a variable (`i`) that is declared with `var` in a higher scope, causing a **[closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)** around `i` that persists into each call to that function. If you change the variable declaration from `var i` to `let i` (which gives `i` block level scope and ensures that a separate `i` value is created upon each loop iteration), the problem will be solved.

The first one happens to produce a result that you are OK with simply by accident. There is only one item in the array, so its `length` is `1` and therefore, your loop never gets the chance to iterate a second time and show you that both iterations use the same `i` value.

Comment: @melpomene Yep, just saw that. Edited last part of the answer. First part is correct though.